# parse logstash index data with sed, awk, tr

Tags: awk, sed, tr

How can I use sed/awk/tr to parse the following lines of text:

`green  open   logstash-2016.02.19   5   1    2052356            0      2.1gb            1gb
green  open   logstash-2016.03.06   5   1    2045820            0      2.1gb            1gb
green  open   logstash-2016.01.10   5   1    1944711            0      1.8gb        940.4mb
green  open   logstash-2016.01.02   5   1    1505350            0      1.4gb        738.4mb`

And get rid of 'green open' and the spaces in between up to 'logstash-2016.foo'.

And then get rid of everything to the right of that except the right two columns of info. For example '2.1gb            1gb' and have only one space in between those two?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

could do:

`awk '{line=$3; for(i=0;i<NF+1;i++){if(i==8 || i==9){line=line" "$i;}}print line;}' test.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Use awk like this:

```
awk '{print $3, $8, $9}' logstash.txt
```

- assuming your file is name `logstash.txt`
- `$3, $8, $9` select the columns number 3,8,9